# How to get text inside array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, return-value, paragraph, xgettext

I have this array:

```
var arr  = ['<p id="p1">Paragraph 1<p>', '<p id="p2">Paragraph 2<p>', '<p id="p3">Paragraph 3<p>']
```

How can I get the text `Paragraph 3` from this array?

Comment: If you know you want the text "Paragraph 3", why do you need to get it from the array?  If you don't know that, then by what criteria are you looking for content?

Comment: Begs the questions, why do you have an Array of HTML markup in the first place? What is ultimately going to be done with it? Why do you only need the text content? Is it tied to something else you're trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
$(arr[2]).prop('innerHTML');
```

or:

```
$(arr[2]).html();
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kyy6Q/)**

Comment: `$(arr[2]).html();` ought to work as well. Each of these solutions tells jQuery to parse the string as a DOM element, then pull the `innerHTML` property off that element.

Answer (score 1):

You can strip the inner text by chopping up the string using the `split()` method.

```
<script>

var arr  = ['<p id="p1">Paragraph 1<p>', '<p id="p2">Paragraph 2<p>', '<p id="p3">Paragraph 3<p>']

/* Even works with closed <p> element */

var arr  = ['<p id="p1">Paragraph 1</p>', '<p id="p2">Paragraph 2</p>', '<p id="p3">Paragraph 3</p>']

alert(arr[2].split('>')[1].split('<')[0])
</script>
```